# mhddfs not working as expected

Tags: mount, hard-drive, raid

when I run `df -h` I get:

```
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2                         74G  3.0G   67G   5% /
none                             4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                             712M  4.0K  712M   1% /dev
tmpfs                            145M  1.2M  144M   1% /run
none                             5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                             722M     0  722M   0% /run/shm
none                             100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1                        511M  3.4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb1                        1.9T   71M  1.9T   1% /mount1
/dev/sdc1                        1.9T   71M  1.9T   1% /mount2
/dev/sde1                        466G   26M  466G   1% /mount3
/dev/sdd                         466G   16M  466G   1% /mount4
/mount1;/mount2;/mount3;/mount4  4.6T  183M  4.6T   1% /NAS
```

But as you can see the `/NAS` is `4.6T` when it should be `1.9T + 1.9T + 466G + 466G = ~ 5T`!!

So I mount the hard drives like this on the `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sdb1 /mount1       exfat defaults 0 0
/dev/sdc1 /mount2       exfat defaults 0 0
/dev/sde1 /mount3       exfat defaults 0 0
/dev/sdd  /mount4       exfat defaults 0 0
```

And on the `/etc/rc.local` I run the command:

```
sudo mhddfs /mount1,/mount2,/mount3,/mount4 /NAS -o allow_other
```

### What is going wrong?

---

#### sudo fdisk -l

of /dev/sde1 and /dev/sdd

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdd'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdd: 500.1 GB, 500105740288 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976769024 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sde: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sde1               2   976773167   488386583    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1.9T + 466G)*2 = (1.9T + (466/1024)T)*2 = 4.7T

The error (<=3%) seems okay to me.

Comment: Whoops you are right! Just seems to round down everything! I checked just "df" and it looked better!

Comment: This one made me smile!  ;-) (Upvoted!)